# 'Illegal Plan' message when tagging training data with Vocab types

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I'm trying to tag my training data using vocab files to reduce the number of training phrases I need to add e.g. use a Bill vocab which allows the use of 'bill' or 'invoice' interchangeably. I have added a Bill enum type and an Bill vocab file. However when I try to tag the word 'bill' in my training phrase with value Bill:Bill I get an 'Illegal Plan' message in my training entry.

My goal is an action. Note that 'bill' is not an expected input to my action. I'm just trying to minimise the number of training phrases I need to add.

Also, could you explain the function of 'Role' in training data? I don't see an explanation in the documentation.

```
num (Bill) {
  symbol (Bill)
}
```

```
vocab (Bill) {
  "Bill" {"Bill", "bill", "invoice", "account balance"}
}
```

```
[g:FaqBill] check my (bill)[v:Bill:Bill]
```

I would expect the NL model to compile successfully but I get an 'Illegal Plan' message in my training entry.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to do the same thing and was able to get the expected plan.

[image]

Here are the parts of my attempt at reproducing the behavior you described. Please check each file to see if it matches the code below:

Enum:

```
enum (Bill) {
  symbol (Bill)
}
```

Vocabulary:

```
vocab (Bill) {
  "Bill" {"Bill", "bill", "invoice", "account balance"}
}
```

Action:

```
action (GetBill) {
  description (Gets the bill)
  type (Search)
  collect {
    input (bill) {
      type (Bill)
      min (Required) max (One)
    }
  }
  output (Bill)
}
```

Action JS:

```
module.exports = {
  function: GetBill
}

function GetBill (bill) {
  return bill
}
```

With these 4 elements, I was able to get the utterance training plan shown in the screenshot provided above.

Comment: Thanks but the difference is that my GetBill action does not take a Bill as an input as it doesn't need to. I just want that action to be invoked whether I say 'get my bill' or 'get my invoice'. Are you saying that I would need to add 'Bill' as an optional input? I should have mentioned that the training seems to work even though it has the 'Illegal Plan' message.

Comment: Ah, in that case, you do not need any vocab file. Your `GetBill` action would take zero inputs and output a Bill concept. You would then train the types of utterances you expect your users to use when asking for their bill ("Show my my bill", "Give me my invoice", "Show balance", etc. With enough examples, Bixby will be able to correctly call the GetBill action when similar utterances are used.

Comment: Thanks but I was hoping to avoid having to train 'show me my bill', 'show me my invoice', 'show me my balance', 'show me my account' and the other variants of 'show me' x 4, by using synonyms because it's slow to add training phrases in Bixby Studio. I'd like to just have 'Show me my $bill', 'Give me my $bill' etc

Comment: You wouldn't have to train every single potential variant. Just a few examples would do the trick since Bixby should learn that the "Show me my..." convention means that the user wants to view the bill and that the GetBill Action needs to be invoked.